# Ethernet PHY - Buffer Type

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, ethernet, phy

I'm going through the datasheet of this PHY Transceiver [LAN8701A](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN8710A)

On Page 14, table 2.2, it is mentioned as buffer types.

This is the first time I'm coming across the table called buffer types.
Can someone explain what are the buffer types and why are they used?

Why can't we see this table in other types of datasheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "buffer types" table you are seeing on page 14 is the legend for the "buffer type" column in the pin function description tables 2.1 to 2.7. These refer to the type of internal drivers/receivers that exist inside the integrated circuit for each pin. The word "buffer" is used because these drivers/receivers act to isolate the outside world from the integrated circuit inside the device package.

You see, not every pin on an integrated circuit can perform any task. Some pins are used as digital inputs, digital outputs, analog inputs, analog outputs, etc. Each pin type has a different circuit on the inside of the chip.

I have seen other datasheets that contain this kind of information. This [STM32H723](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h723zg.pdf) datasheet has something similar on page 56, although not as detailed. Often times the buffer type of a pin can be inferred from its functionality. (For example, pins labeled as XIN and XOUT are often understood to be the crystal input and inverter output pins respectively, without having to be labeled as ICLK and OCLK buffer types)

In other chips, some pins can have multiple functions, in which case multiple sets of circuits exist inside the package and the inputs/outputs are *multiplexed* to allow you to select which kind you want to use. In this case however, the datasheet is just telling you what kind of I/O each pin is.

To summarize, this table describes the input/output capability of each pin on the device.

- IS/VIS seem to be pretty general digital inputs
- O12/VO8 seem to be standard push-pull outputs
- VOD seems to be a standard open-drain output
- PU and PD are used to describe the digital outputs
- The rest are pretty self explanatory

Hopefully that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

The types are used in previous table to define what kind of properties each IO pin of the chip has. Such as is it an input, output, analog, digital, or supply pin.

Almos all datasheets define what kind of pins the chip has in some way, a separate table with short mnemonics is just one way out of many ways of defining it.

Otherwise you are not able to guess from the pin names if they are input or outpus, analog or digital pins, or supply pins or data pins, etc.